# A real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble showing the following.

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on the closed interval $[0,1]$. Prove that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a polynomial $P$ such that
$$\sup_{0 \le x\le 1} |f(x)-P(x)|+\sup_{0 \le x \le 1} |f'(x)-P'(x)| \le \epsilon.$$

Any hint or suggestion?

Comment: Hint: You know, that polynomials are dense in $C[0,1]$, right? Now $f'$ is continuous, so there is some polynomial such that your second term is $< \epsilon/2$ ... now integrate.

Comment: I'm a bit curious: how does this question relate to measure theory?

Comment: @martini: why don't you write that as an answer?

Comment: @D.Thomine: I don't think it does, so I have changed the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: You know [Weierstrass's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_approximation_theorem), right? Since $f'$ is continuous by assumption, there is some Polynomial $Q$ such that 
$$
\sup_{0 \le x \le 1} |f'(x) - Q(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}2 
$$
Now integrate ...

HTH, AB,

Comment: thanks! I got it! but just curious what is HTH and AB?

Comment: HTH = "hope this helps", AB = "allzeit bereit" (german Scout motto)